# MySQL error when trying to select data from a homemade Joomla component

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to create my first Joomla component. I am working often with MySQL and .NET but I'm rather new in the development of Joomla stuff, so pls forgive my newbie-type things...
Basically I am trying to retrieve user info from a shop table to display the results in the Joomla backend.
Looking at Joomla doc, I am setting up this code in the admin model file:

```
protected function getStuff()
{
    // Initialize variables.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Select some fields
    $query = "select f_name, l_name, street, city, zip, phone, email from #__thetable_name order by l_name asc";

    $db->setQuery($query);
    
    return $query;
}
```

and whatever other attempt I make, such as Joomla doc recommended syntax:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('f_name', 'l_name', 'street', 'city', 'zip', 'phone', 'email'))); 
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__table_name')); 
$query->order('l_name ASC');
```

I always get the same error msg: "500 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 20' at line 1
"

Interestingly, there is no 'LIMIT 20' in my query and the query is perfectly valid when I test it in MySQL Workbench, so I am really puzzled as to what I do wrong...

Am using the latest Joomla 3.9.23.

Could anyone yell at me and tell me how to fix this?

Thx and happy (healthy) holidays

Philippe

Comment: Somewhere there is an earlier error that you are not pinpointing.  We cannot help you with the currently provided info.  Please improve your diagnostic details and always post all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Why are you "gettingStuff" and returning the query object? Are you reusing the query later?